# How to reverse bits of a byte?

Tags: php, algorithm, bit-manipulation

For example, in PHP, how would I reverse the bits of the byte `11011111` to `11111011`?

Comment: well, in this case rotate right by 5 positions :P

Comment: Your question needs a bit more clarification. For instance, is this a string or an actual integer whose bits you are attempting to flip? Context is very important when asking a question.

Comment: @klez - +1 lol, you almost made me spit my coffee on my keyboard =P

Comment: +1 to Kletz, but for this case you can do much simpler thing: assign with 0b11111011 value (for some architectures it could be much efficient ;) ).

Comment: @Roman +1, yes, yours is much simpler XD

Answer (score 17):

The straight forward approach is to perform 8 masks, 8 rotates, and 7 additions:

```
$blah = $blah & 128 >> 7 + $blah & 64 >> 5 + $blah & 32 >> 3 + $blah & 16 >> 1 + $blah & 8 << 1 + $blah & 4 << 3 + $blah & 2 << 5 + $blah & 1 << 7;
```

Comment: @Kinopiko: 3 upvotes, with mine. Do you have a better solution. Post it and you'll get my vote too!

Comment: Well, it is answering the question :-)

Comment: which mathematical theorem or algorithm is this answer based on?

Comment: "The Principle of Brute Force"

Comment: It's not a theorem, its literally just reconstructing a byte by rearranging the bits. I had to use parenthesis and OR instead of + though: `(128&n)>>7|(64&n)>>5|(32&n)>>3|(16&n)>>1|(8&n)<<1|(4&n)<<3|(2&n)<<5|(1&n)<<7`

Answer (score 17):

If you have already the bits in the form of a string, use [strrev](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php).

If not, convert first the byte to its binary representation by using [decbin](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php), then reverse using strrev, then go back to byte (if necessary) by using [bindec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php).

Comment: The best answer IMO that will work for general cases. Those bit shifting, rotation etc are just targeting the example value given and won't work for random binary strings ..

Comment: +1 This is what I would have suggested had I not botched the initial understanding.

Answer (score 16):

Check the section on reversing bit sequences in [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious). Should be easy to adapt one of the techniques into PHP.

While probably not practical for PHP, there's a particularly fascinating one using 3 64bit operations:

```
unsigned char b; // reverse this (8-bit) byte
b = (b * 0x0202020202ULL & 0x010884422010ULL) % 1023;
```

Comment: Can you explain what "ULL" means here?

Comment: @mask that's an unsigned long long, the suffix tells the compiler that what proceeds it is a 64-bit unsigned integer literal.

Comment: why it's a solution if it is not practical for php?

Answer (score 10):

The quickest way, but also the one requiring more space is a lookup, whereby each possible value of a byte (256 if you go for the whole range), is associated with its "reversed" equivalent.

If you only have a few such bytes to handle, bit-wise operators will do but that will be slower, maybe something like:

```
function reverseBits($in) {
  $out = 0;

  if ($in & 0x01) $out |= 0x80;
  if ($in & 0x02) $out |= 0x40;
  if ($in & 0x04) $out |= 0x20;
  if ($in & 0x08) $out |= 0x10;
  if ($in & 0x10) $out |= 0x08;
  if ($in & 0x20) $out |= 0x04;
  if ($in & 0x40) $out |= 0x02;
  if ($in & 0x80) $out |= 0x01;

  return $out;
}
```

Comment: Historically, I've found that having a 256 byte lookup table is the fastest way to achieve it as it's just a lookup. 256 bytes is not a lot of space to dedicate to something like this if it need to be fast. Though the above reverseBits function is about as small and tight as you can get the code without having a lookup. Also for one small optimization you could change the first { $out |= 0x80;} to { $out = 0x80;} as you know that first time you're ORing with 0.

Comment: @skirmish, agreed, I'd tend to use the lookup array in most cases.  An intermediate solution, would be to have a smaller array, for 4 bits, and do two lookups with the associated multiplication/division for the leftmost bit-quad). This way of doing can also be used to 
deal with say integers rather that bytes.  (The downside of the lookup approach is that its space requirement grows exponentially, whereby the coded appraoch linearly  (w/ regards to the number of bits).

Answer (score 3):

This is O(n) with the bit length.  Just think of the input as a stack and write to the output stack.

My attempt at writing this in PHP.

```
function bitrev ($inBits, $bitlen){
   $cloneBits=$inBits;
   $inBits=0;
   $count=0;

   while ($count < $bitlen){
      $count=$count+1;
      $inBits=$inBits<<1;
      $inBits=$inBits|($cloneBits & 0x1);
      $cloneBits=$cloneBits>>1;
   }

    return $inBits;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Some people have been suggesting a lookup table, while I have been making one:

```
[
        0x00, 0x80, 0x40, 0xC0, 0x20, 0xA0, 0x60, 0xE0, 0x10, 0x90, 0x50, 0xD0, 0x30, 0xB0, 0x70, 0xF0,
        0x08, 0x88, 0x48, 0xC8, 0x28, 0xA8, 0x68, 0xE8, 0x18, 0x98, 0x58, 0xD8, 0x38, 0xB8, 0x78, 0xF8,
        0x04, 0x84, 0x44, 0xC4, 0x24, 0xA4, 0x64, 0xE4, 0x14, 0x94, 0x54, 0xD4, 0x34, 0xB4, 0x74, 0xF4,
        0x0C, 0x8C, 0x4C, 0xCC, 0x2C, 0xAC, 0x6C, 0xEC, 0x1C, 0x9C, 0x5C, 0xDC, 0x3C, 0xBC, 0x7C, 0xFC,
        0x02, 0x82, 0x42, 0xC2, 0x22, 0xA2, 0x62, 0xE2, 0x12, 0x92, 0x52, 0xD2, 0x32, 0xB2, 0x72, 0xF2,
        0x0A, 0x8A, 0x4A, 0xCA, 0x2A, 0xAA, 0x6A, 0xEA, 0x1A, 0x9A, 0x5A, 0xDA, 0x3A, 0xBA, 0x7A, 0xFA,
        0x06, 0x86, 0x46, 0xC6, 0x26, 0xA6, 0x66, 0xE6, 0x16, 0x96, 0x56, 0xD6, 0x36, 0xB6, 0x76, 0xF6,
        0x0E, 0x8E, 0x4E, 0xCE, 0x2E, 0xAE, 0x6E, 0xEE, 0x1E, 0x9E, 0x5E, 0xDE, 0x3E, 0xBE, 0x7E, 0xFE,
        0x01, 0x81, 0x41, 0xC1, 0x21, 0xA1, 0x61, 0xE1, 0x11, 0x91, 0x51, 0xD1, 0x31, 0xB1, 0x71, 0xF1,
        0x09, 0x89, 0x49, 0xC9, 0x29, 0xA9, 0x69, 0xE9, 0x19, 0x99, 0x59, 0xD9, 0x39, 0xB9, 0x79, 0xF9,
        0x05, 0x85, 0x45, 0xC5, 0x25, 0xA5, 0x65, 0xE5, 0x15, 0x95, 0x55, 0xD5, 0x35, 0xB5, 0x75, 0xF5,
        0x0D, 0x8D, 0x4D, 0xCD, 0x2D, 0xAD, 0x6D, 0xED, 0x1D, 0x9D, 0x5D, 0xDD, 0x3D, 0xBD, 0x7D, 0xFD,
        0x03, 0x83, 0x43, 0xC3, 0x23, 0xA3, 0x63, 0xE3, 0x13, 0x93, 0x53, 0xD3, 0x33, 0xB3, 0x73, 0xF3,
        0x0B, 0x8B, 0x4B, 0xCB, 0x2B, 0xAB, 0x6B, 0xEB, 0x1B, 0x9B, 0x5B, 0xDB, 0x3B, 0xBB, 0x7B, 0xFB,
        0x07, 0x87, 0x47, 0xC7, 0x27, 0xA7, 0x67, 0xE7, 0x17, 0x97, 0x57, 0xD7, 0x37, 0xB7, 0x77, 0xF7,
        0x0F, 0x8F, 0x4F, 0xCF, 0x2F, 0xAF, 0x6F, 0xEF, 0x1F, 0x9F, 0x5F, 0xDF, 0x3F, 0xBF, 0x7F, 0xFF,
][$byte]
```

And here's a character version:

```
[
    "\x00", "\x80", "\x40", "\xC0", "\x20", "\xA0", "\x60", "\xE0", "\x10", "\x90", "\x50", "\xD0", "\x30", "\xB0", "\x70", "\xF0",
    "\x08", "\x88", "\x48", "\xC8", "\x28", "\xA8", "\x68", "\xE8", "\x18", "\x98", "\x58", "\xD8", "\x38", "\xB8", "\x78", "\xF8",
    "\x04", "\x84", "\x44", "\xC4", "\x24", "\xA4", "\x64", "\xE4", "\x14", "\x94", "\x54", "\xD4", "\x34", "\xB4", "\x74", "\xF4",
    "\x0C", "\x8C", "\x4C", "\xCC", "\x2C", "\xAC", "\x6C", "\xEC", "\x1C", "\x9C", "\x5C", "\xDC", "\x3C", "\xBC", "\x7C", "\xFC",
    "\x02", "\x82", "\x42", "\xC2", "\x22", "\xA2", "\x62", "\xE2", "\x12", "\x92", "\x52", "\xD2", "\x32", "\xB2", "\x72", "\xF2",
    "\x0A", "\x8A", "\x4A", "\xCA", "\x2A", "\xAA", "\x6A", "\xEA", "\x1A", "\x9A", "\x5A", "\xDA", "\x3A", "\xBA", "\x7A", "\xFA",
    "\x06", "\x86", "\x46", "\xC6", "\x26", "\xA6", "\x66", "\xE6", "\x16", "\x96", "\x56", "\xD6", "\x36", "\xB6", "\x76", "\xF6",
    "\x0E", "\x8E", "\x4E", "\xCE", "\x2E", "\xAE", "\x6E", "\xEE", "\x1E", "\x9E", "\x5E", "\xDE", "\x3E", "\xBE", "\x7E", "\xFE",
    "\x01", "\x81", "\x41", "\xC1", "\x21", "\xA1", "\x61", "\xE1", "\x11", "\x91", "\x51", "\xD1", "\x31", "\xB1", "\x71", "\xF1",
    "\x09", "\x89", "\x49", "\xC9", "\x29", "\xA9", "\x69", "\xE9", "\x19", "\x99", "\x59", "\xD9", "\x39", "\xB9", "\x79", "\xF9",
    "\x05", "\x85", "\x45", "\xC5", "\x25", "\xA5", "\x65", "\xE5", "\x15", "\x95", "\x55", "\xD5", "\x35", "\xB5", "\x75", "\xF5",
    "\x0D", "\x8D", "\x4D", "\xCD", "\x2D", "\xAD", "\x6D", "\xED", "\x1D", "\x9D", "\x5D", "\xDD", "\x3D", "\xBD", "\x7D", "\xFD",
    "\x03", "\x83", "\x43", "\xC3", "\x23", "\xA3", "\x63", "\xE3", "\x13", "\x93", "\x53", "\xD3", "\x33", "\xB3", "\x73", "\xF3",
    "\x0B", "\x8B", "\x4B", "\xCB", "\x2B", "\xAB", "\x6B", "\xEB", "\x1B", "\x9B", "\x5B", "\xDB", "\x3B", "\xBB", "\x7B", "\xFB",
    "\x07", "\x87", "\x47", "\xC7", "\x27", "\xA7", "\x67", "\xE7", "\x17", "\x97", "\x57", "\xD7", "\x37", "\xB7", "\x77", "\xF7",
    "\x0F", "\x8F", "\x4F", "\xCF", "\x2F", "\xAF", "\x6F", "\xEF", "\x1F", "\x9F", "\x5F", "\xDF", "\x3F", "\xBF", "\x7F", "\xFF",
][ord($byte)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to get this book, there is whole chapter about bits reversion:
[Hacker's Delight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201914654). But please check content first if this suits you.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with using a look up table as (for larger integers) the amount of time necessary to load it into memory trumps processing performance.

I also use a bitwise masking approach for a O(logn) solution, which looks like:

```
MASK = onescompliment of 0    
while SIZE is greater than 0
  SIZE = SIZE shiftRight 1
  MASK = MASK xor (MASK shiftLeft SIZE)
  output = ((output shiftRight  SIZE) bitwiseAnd MASK) bitwiseOR ((onescompliment of MASK) bitwiseAnd (output shfitLeft SIZE))
```

The advantage of this approach is it handles the size of your integer as an argument

in php this might look like:

```
function bitrev($bitstring, $size){

  $mask = ~0;
  while ($size > 0){

    $size = $size >> 1;
    $mask = $mask ^ ($mask << $size);
    $bitstring = (($bitstring >> $size) & $mask) | ((~$mask) & ($bitstring << $size));
  }
}
```

unless I screwed up my php somewhere :(

Comment: if you're performing the operation just once, a lookup table is bad. But if it's a frequent operation, it should outperform any other approach.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge! If we're really just talking about 8-bit unsigned, then the quickest way, according to my tests, is to use an array (0 - 255), which value holds the reverse int value.

```
$lsb = [
    0 => 0,
    1 => 128,
    2 => 64,
    3 => 192,
    4 => 32,
    5 => 160,
    ...
    252 => 63,
    253 => 191,
    254 => 127,
    255 => 255,
];

function getByteLSBF($lsb, $byte) {
    return $lsb[$byte];
}
```

The next fastest approach was surprisingly the string conversion approach described by @Konamiman (about the third slower) - which really baffled me since the direct bit manipulations were the slowest (more than double slower):

```
function getByteLSBfirst(int $byte): int
{
   $lsbFirst = 0;
   for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
      $lsbFirst = ($lsbFirst << 1) | ($byte & 1);
      $byte = $byte >> 1;
   }

   return $lsbFirst;
}
```

I tested all three approaches with the same random int (byte) in 10,000 iterations simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

In 1984, I came up with this solution (on a Commodore Vic20 and memory was a premium back then). So my two-line calculation in BASIC did the trick. Simple, quick and no memory-hogging table.

Since `=11001111=207`,  input this in W.

The program returns `V = 243... = 11110011`

PROGRAM:

```
input w: v=0: for x=0 to 7
if w>(2^(7-x))-1 then v=v+(2^x): w=w-(2^(7-x))
next
print v
```