# How do I perform a circular rotation of a byte?

Tags: c, bitmask

I'm trying to implement a function that performs a circular rotation of a byte to the left and to the right.

I wrote the same code for both operations. For example, if you are rotating left `1010` becomes `0101`. Is this right?

```
unsigned char rotl(unsigned char c) {
    int w;
    unsigned char s = c;
    for (w = 7; w >= 0; w--) {
       int b = (int)getBit(c, w);//
       if (b == 0) {
           s = clearBit(s, 7 - w);
       } else if (b == 1) {
           s = setBit(s, 7 - w);
       }
    }
    return s;
}

unsigned char getBit(unsigned char c, int n) {
    return c = (c & (1 << n)) >> n;
}

unsigned char setBit(unsigned char c, int n) {
    return c = c | (1 << n);
}

unsigned char clearBit(unsigned char c, int n) {
    return c = c &(~(1 << n));
}
```

Comment: why can't you use shift `<<` operator directly?

Comment: Probably faster to sum a shift left by n plus shift right by 8-n

Comment: You're making this too hard. Rotating X left N bits is just `(X << N) | (X >> (8 - N))`.  Rotating right M bits is just rotating left `(8 - M)` bits.

Comment: How do i do that if the prototype of the function is:           unsigned char rotl(unsigned char c)

Comment: It doesn't seem to me as if you are performing a "circular rotation", but rather that you're reversing the bits. Which is it that you want?

Comment: How do I perform the circular motion both left and right

Comment: @Manuel: I'm pretty sure there is something you misunderstand, because you can't do circular rotation without a specification of how many bits the byte should be rotated. Please be more specific in what it is you want to do, rather than use terms that you may or may not understand properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Circular shift operations in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508/circular-shift-operations-in-c)

Comment: For example, if you are rotating left, 1010 becomes 0101

Comment: @manuel that didn't help. Do you think `10100000` becomes `01010000` or `00000101`? The first is a circular shift right by one bit, the second is a bit reversal. Very different operations!

Answer (score 20):

There is no rotation operator in C, but if you write:

```
unsigned char rotl(unsigned char c)
{
    return (c << 1) | (c >> 7);
}
```

then, according to this: http://www.linux-kongress.org/2009/slides/compiler_survey_felix_von_leitner.pdf (page 56), compilers will figure out what you want to do and perform the rotation it in only one (very fast) instruction.

Comment: I don't think this answer helps Manuel because he seems to be confused about what he is trying to do but I'm up voting because of the cool trick with reference!

Answer (score 15):

Reading the answers and comments so far, there seems to be some confusion about what you are trying to accomplish - this may be because of the words you use. In bit manipulation, there are several "standard" things you can do. I will summarize some of these to help clarify different concepts. **In all that follows, I will use `abcdefgh` to denote 8 bits** (could be ones or zeros) - and as they move around, the same letter will refer to the same bit (maybe in a different position); if a bit becomes "definitely `0` or `1`, I will denote it as such).

1) **Bit shifting**: This is essentially a "fast multiply or divide by a power of 2". The symbol used is `<<` for "left shift" (multiply) or `>>` for right shift (divide).  Thus

```
abcdefgh >> 2 = 00abcdef
```

(equivalent to "divide by four") and

```
abcdefgh << 3 = abcdefgh000
```

(equivalent to "multiply by eight" - and assuming there was "space" to shift the `abc` into; otherwise this might result in an overflow)

2) **Bit masking**: sometimes you want to set certain bits to zero. You do this by doing an AND operation with a number that has ones where you want to preserve a bit, and zeros where you want to clear a bit.

```
abcdefgh & 01011010 = 0b0de0g0
```

Or if you want to make sure certain bits are one, you use the OR operation:

```
abcdefgh | 01011010 = a1c11f1h
```

3) **Circular shift**: this is a bit trickier - there are instances where you want to "move bits around", with the ones that "fall off at one end" re-appearing at the other end. There is no symbol for this in C, and no "quick instruction" (although most processors have a built-in instruction which assembler code can take advantage of for FFT calculations and such).  If you want to do a "left circular shift" by three positions:

```
circshift(abcdefgh, 3) = defghabc
```

(note: there is no `circshift` function in the standard C libraries, although it exists in other languages - e.g. Matlab). By the same token a "right shift" would be

```
circshift(abcdefgh, -2) = ghabcdef
```

4) **Bit reversal**: Sometimes you need to reverse the bits in a number. When reversing the bits, there is no "left" or "right" - reversed is reversed:

```
reverse(abcdefgh) = hgfedcba
```

Again, there isn't actually a "reverse" function in standard C libraries.

Now, let's take a look at some tricks for implementing these last two functions (`circshift` and `reverse`) in C. There are entire websites devoted to "clever ways to manipulate bits" - see for example [this excellent one](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html). for a wonderful collection of "bit hacks", although some of these may be a little advanced...

```
unsigned char circshift(unsigned char x, int n) {
  return (x << n) | (x >> (8 - n));
}
```

This uses two tricks from the above: shifting bits, and using the OR operation to set bits to specific values. Let's look at how it works, for n = 3 (note - I am ignoring bits above the 8th bit since the return type of the function is `unsigned char`):

```
(abcdefgh << 3)       = defgh000
(abcdefgh >> (8 - 3)) = 00000abc
```

Taking the bitwise OR of these two gives

```
defgh000 | 00000abc = defghabc
```

Which is exactly the result we wanted. Note also that `a << n` is the same as `a >> (-n)`; in other words, right shifting by a negative number is the same as left shifting by a positive number, and *vice versa*.

Now let's look at the `reverse` function. There are "fast ways" and "slow ways" to do this. Your code above gave a "very slow" way - let me show you a "very fast" way, assuming that your compiler allows the use of 64 bit (`long long`) integers.

```
unsigned char reverse(unsigned char b) {
  return (b * 0x0202020202ULL & 0x010884422010ULL) % 1023;
}
```

You may ask yourself "what just happened"??? Let me show you:

```
b = abcdefgh

* 0x0000000202020202 = 00000000 00000000 0000000a bcdefgha bcdefgha bcdefgha bcdefgha bcdefgh0
& 0x0000010884422010 = 00000000 00000000 00000001 00001000 10000100 01000010 00100000 00010000
                     = 00000000 00000000 0000000a 0000f000 b0000g00 0c0000h0 00d00000 000e0000
```

Note that we now have all the bits exactly once - they are just in a rather strange pattern. The modulo 1023 division "collapses" the bits of interest on top of each other - it's like magic, and I can't explain it. The result is indeed

```
hgfedcba
```

A slightly less obscure way to achieve the same thing (less efficient, but works for larger numbers quite efficiently) recognizes that if you swap adjacent bits , then adjacent bit pairs, then adjacent nibbles (4 bit groups), etc - you end up with a complete bit reversal. In that case, a byte reversal becomes

```
unsigned char bytereverse(unsigned char b) {
  b = (b & 0x55) << 1 | (b & 0xAA) >> 1; // swap adjacent bits
  b = (b & 0x33) << 2 | (b & 0xCC) >> 2; // swap adjacent pairs
  b = (b & 0x0F) << 4 | (b & 0xF0) >> 4; // swap nibbles
  return b;
}
```

In this case the following happens to byte `b = abcdefgh`:

```
b & 0x55 = abcdefgh & 01010101 = 0b0d0f0h << 1 = b0d0f0h0
b & 0xAA = abcdefgh & 10101010 = a0c0e0g0 >> 1 = 0a0c0e0g
OR these two to get badcfehg
```

Next line:

```
b & 0x33 = badcfehg & 00110011 = 00dc00hg << 2 = dc00hg00
b & 0xCC = badcfehg & 11001100 = ba00fe00 >> 2 = 00ba00fe
OR these to get dcbahgfe
```

last line:

```
b & 0x0F = dcbahgfe & 00001111 = 0000hgfe << 4 = hgfe0000
b & 0xF0 = dcbahgfe & 11110000 = dcba0000 >> 4 = 0000dcba
OR these to get hgfedcba
```

Which is the reversed byte you were after. It should be easy to see how just a couple more lines (similar to the above) get you to a reversed integer (32 bits). As the size of the number increases, this trick becomes more and more efficient, comparatively.

I trust that the answer you were looking for is "somewhere" in the above. If nothing else I hope you have a clearer understanding of the possibilities of bit manipulation in C.

Comment: To add, if we don't know byte size of data type, I think we can do: `(x >> n)|(x << sizeof(x)*8 - n)`

Answer (score 4):

If, as according to your comments, you want to shift one bit exactly, then one easy way to accomplish that would be this:

```
unsigned char rotl(unsigned char c)
{
    return((c << 1) | (c >> 7));
}
```

What your code does is reversing the bits; not rotating them. For instance, it would make 10111001 into 10011101, not 01110011.

Comment: Yes. `(c >> 1) | (c << 7)`