# Reversing a byte with logic diagrams

Tags: boolean-logic, circuit

I would like to use circuit components to reverse a byte. But the catch is I can't use a black box or any gates. Is there a way I can do this? I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602823/in-c-c-whats-the-simplest-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-bits-in-a-byte) to reverse a byte, but I'm not sure how else to reverse it. I tried messing around with MUXs to no avail. Any guidance here would be much appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: To clarify further, I would like to take an input as a byte into a logic diagram and I would like the output to be the bytes reversed. The constraints are that I CAN'T use logic gates (and, or, xor, etc) or just use a black box.

Comment: this question is very vague. can you elaborate?

Comment: I have elaborated some more. Please let me know if I have provided sufficient detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually figured out the answer after some research. It can be done like this. [image: Reverse a byte with circuits]