# Reverse order of boost::dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost, reverse, boost-dynamic-bitset

Is there a clean way to return the reverse ordering of a `boost::dynamic_bitset` object?

For example:
`01001100`
becomes
`00110010`.
The simplest solution I can think of is to convert the bitset to a string, reverse the string and convert it back to a bitset, but this seems a rather slow method that nullifies the speed of bitstring operations.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the length constrained to whole blocks? That allows a "reverse copy to temporary, reverse each block, copy back" implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::dynamic_bitset` doesn't have iterators, so a long range of comfy STL solutions like, off the top of my head, `std::reverse` or `std::swap` or their `boost` counterparts are not available, I reckon that a good way would be to make your own trivial reverse method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

void reverse(boost::dynamic_bitset<> &bs)
{
    for (size_t begin = 0, end = bs.size() - 1; begin < end; begin++, end--)
    {
        bool b = bs[end];
        bs[end] = bs[begin];
        bs[begin] = b;
    }
}

int main()
{
    size_t size = 8;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bs(size, 50);

    std::cout << "Normal:  " << bs << std::endl;
    reverse(bs);
    std::cout << "Reverse: " << bs << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Normal:  00110010
Reverse: 01001100
```

[**Live demo**](https://godbolt.org/z/qP4GYejqx)

Comment: It appears that the "Block" part of `boost::dynamic_bitset` is only half done. You can't loop over the blocks until the middle block, so a block-by-block swap is impossible.

Comment: I think we can do better. Let me check

Comment: @sehe, well if it's possible you're certanly the right person for the job. As a matter of precaution, I already changed *the best way* to *a good way* ;)

Comment: (Cheers :)) Okay I [found what I was looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66874339/85371) on my machine.. _Samples 1120000 mean: 90.3283 min: 0 max: 192 stddev: 55.9233
Average cost **3.69335μs**_ /cc @MSalters

Answer (score 2):

You can do better with the very fortunate

```
 #define BOOST_DYNAMIC_BITSET_DONT_USE_FRIENDS
```

which I noticed first because it's used in other third-party libraries (I forget the name, but it was AI/ML related).

I had a version here that wasn't very generic because it used size-specific bit twiddling hacks (to reverse e.g. byte or uint32). You might be interested in those:

- see http://aggregate.org/MAGIC/#Bit%20Reversal
- or [https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel)

You can still see the uint32-dedicated version  **[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/zf4c7c175)**.

### Generic Version

Since then I spotted this nice answer: [In C/C++ what's the simplest way to reverse the order of bits in a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602823/in-c-c-whats-the-simplest-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-bits-in-a-byte/61109975#61109975) and it gave a reasonably efficient in-place reverse algorithm for power-of-2 width integral types. So, now we have the completely generic:

```
// make sure it's globally defined
#define BOOST_DYNAMIC_BITSET_DONT_USE_FRIENDS
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Block, typename Allocator>
void reverse(boost::dynamic_bitset<Block, Allocator>& bs) {
    auto constexpr BLOCK_BIT = sizeof(Block) * CHAR_BIT;
    auto original_size       = bs.size();

    if (auto partial_block = bs.size() % BLOCK_BIT) {
        auto pad = (BLOCK_BIT - partial_block);
        bs.resize(bs.size() + pad);
        bs <<= pad;
    }

    // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61109975/85371
    auto inplace = [](Block& n) {
        static_assert(std::is_unsigned_v<Block>);

        short bits = sizeof(n) * 8;
        Block mask = ~Block(0); // equivalent to uint32_t mask =
                                // 0b11111111111111111111111111111111;

        while (bits >>= 1) {
            mask ^= mask << (bits); // will convert mask to
                                    // 0b00000000000000001111111111111111;
            n = (n & ~mask) >> bits | (n & mask) << bits; // divide and conquer
        }
    };

    for (auto& b : bs.m_bits) {
        inplace(b);
    }
    std::reverse(begin(bs.m_bits), end(bs.m_bits));

    bs.resize(original_size);
}
```

> **NOTE** the reversal will MUCH more efficient for `size()` multiples of `BLOCK_BIT`. This might in some scenario even lead one to prefer `Block = std::uint8_t`.

### Generic Tester/<strike>Benchmark</strike>

Let's write some randomized tests. For ease of implementation we compare the reversed string representation to the string representation of the reverse.

I added tests for varying block sizes and statistics on the sizes and times:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/z1absfa7z)**

```
// For quick testing
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/reverse.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
static auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
#include <boost/accumulators/accumulators.hpp>
#include <boost/accumulators/statistics.hpp>

namespace ba  = boost::accumulators;
namespace bat = ba::tag;

template <typename Block> bool run_test(unsigned n, auto& stats) {
    using BitSet = boost::dynamic_bitset<Block>;

    auto gen = std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<Block>{},
                         std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});

    while (n--) {
        Block init[]{gen(), gen(), gen()};
        auto sz = std::bind(
                std::uniform_int_distribution(0ul, sizeof(init) * CHAR_BIT),
                std::mt19937{std::random_device{}()});

        BitSet bs(std::begin(init), std::end(init));
        bs.resize(sz());
        stats(bs.size());

        std::string expected = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(bs);
        boost::reverse(expected);

        BitSet revclone = bs;
        reverse(revclone);

        auto actual = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(revclone);
        if (expected != actual) {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " '" << bs << "': \n"
                      << "  expected: " << expected << "\n"
                      << "  actual: " << actual << "\n";
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    auto start = now();
    ba::accumulator_set<double,
                        ba::stats<bat::mean, bat::variance, bat::min, bat::max>>
        stats;

    if (run_test<unsigned char>(10'000, stats))
        std::cout << "Completed 10'000 tests with char blocks\n";
    if (run_test<uint16_t>(10'000, stats))
        std::cout << "Completed 10'000 tests with uint16_t blocks\n";
    if (run_test<uint32_t>(100'000, stats))
        std::cout << "Completed 100'000 tests with uint32_t blocks\n";
    if (run_test<uintmax_t>(1'000'000, stats))
        std::cout << "Completed 1'000'000 tests with uintmax_t blocks\n";

    auto cost = ((now() - start)/1.us) / ba::count(stats);

    std::cout
        << "Samples " << ba::count(stats)
        << " mean: " << ba::mean(stats)
        << " min: " << ba::min(stats)
        << " max: " << ba::max(stats)
        << " stddev: " << std::sqrt(ba::variance(stats))
        << "\n";

    std::cout << "Average cost " << cost << "μs\n";
}
```

Prints, on my machine:

```
Completed 10'000 tests with char blocks
Completed 10'000 tests with uint16_t blocks
Completed 100'000 tests with uint32_t blocks
Completed 1'000'000 tests with uintmax_t blocks
Samples 1120000 mean: 90.3283 min: 0 max: 192 stddev: 55.9233
Average cost 3.69335μs

real    0m4,141s
user    0m4,061s
sys     0m0,003s
```

<strike>So, with a mean size of 90 bits, bitsets up to 192 bits can be reversed in less than than 4μs. Not bad.</strike>

### Proper Micro Benchmarks

Using [Nonius](https://github.com/libnonius/nonius), we can get reliable data from predictable tests. For sizes 31, 32, 37 bits net timings are in the 10-30ns range.

Code used:

```
#define NONIUS_RUNNER
#include <nonius/nonius.h++>
#include <nonius/main.h++>

template <typename Block> void run_test(nonius::chronometer& cm, size_t target_size) {
    using BitSet = boost::dynamic_bitset<Block>;

    static const std::string data{
        "0100110111010010010001100111010010010001011100100100111010100010011010"
        "01100000011000010001110111"};

    BitSet bs(data, 0, target_size);
    assert(bs.size() == target_size);

    cm.measure([&] { reverse(bs); });
}

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uchar,     sz=32", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uint8_t>(cm,   32); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uint16_t,  sz=32", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uint16_t>(cm,  32); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uint32_t,  sz=32", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uint32_t>(cm,  32); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uintmax_t, sz=32", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uintmax_t>(cm, 32); })

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uchar,     sz=31", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uint8_t>(cm,   31); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uint16_t,  sz=31", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uint16_t>(cm,  31); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uint32_t,  sz=31", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uint32_t>(cm,  31); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uintmax_t, sz=31", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uintmax_t>(cm, 31); })

NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uchar,     sz=37", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uint8_t>(cm,   37); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uint16_t,  sz=37", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uint16_t>(cm,  37); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uint32_t,  sz=37", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uint32_t>(cm,  37); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("Block=uintmax_t, sz=37", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { run_test<uintmax_t>(cm, 37); })
```

> Full interactive chart: http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/974d10e8-74ae-4fcf-be03-6a0d0e01b5ad/stats.html

[image]

Comment: You surely did, very nice.

Comment: @anastaciu I just realized my timings reflect the tests. Which use string-conversion and reversal as check :) So they are pretty useless. Oh well

Comment: Well, details ;)

Comment: @anastaciu proper [benchmark](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/r4TyTtQ4WV/) with [Nonius](https://github.com/libnonius/nonius): Real timings in the 10-30ns range. [Screenies](https://imgur.com/a/Echz1Or) confirm 32bit favorite on well-aligned input. intmax_t ties for suboptimal sizes. Full interactive chart: http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/974d10e8-74ae-4fcf-be03-6a0d0e01b5ad/stats.html

Comment: Indeed, which was to be expected, really, very good thorough answer, it's a pity I can't double upvote.