# How can I reverse the bits of a 64 bit integer?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, long-integer

Given an unsigned 64-bit integer such as:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

How can I efficiently reverse the bits into something like this?

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602823/in-c-c-whats-the-simplest-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-bits-in-a-byte/2602885

Comment: Expanding from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602823/in-c-c-whats-the-simplest-way-to-reverse-the-order-of-bits-in-a-byte/2602885, I created http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42dd5c2497929e4f but its not exactly _efficient_