# Bitwise operation C

Tags: c, bit

I have this an unsigned int (uint16_t): 391
I want to flip all the  bits around from right to left. That is to say, the rightmost bit becomes the leftmost bit.

I have tried `x = 391 << sizeof(uint16_t)` This seems not to work.

The desired output is: `x = 57728`

My current output is: `x = 1564`

Comment: So what output did you get? [Edit] the question and make that clear,

Comment: Wire in two 16-bit ports, connect them together back-to-front, write to one, read from the other )

Comment: @MartinJames
An demo will do, thanks

Comment: ..or just brute-force it with a loop and shifting mask, probably quicker to write that code than asking this question )

Comment: @izlin No, it doesn't

Comment: How do you expect `<< sizeof(uint16_t)` to flip any bit order? This is basically same as `* 4`. You need to look at the bits in one value and set bits accordingly in your result value. And as you need to do it for all 16 bits, a loop would be useful.

Comment: You're going to have to do it one bit at a time.  Do you know how to [extract and set individual bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981)?

Comment: This was question was already marked as duplicate of [In C/C++ what's the simplest way to reverse the order of bits in a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2602823/694733). Don't know why it was reopened, but your answer is basically there in that question.

Comment: C's shift operators `<<` and `>>` can turn the bit pattern `abcdefgh` into `defgh000` or `000abcde`.  A "circular shift" operator (which C doesn't have built in, although it's a useful exercise to write one) can turn it into `defghabc` or `fghabcde`.  But here you want `hgfedcba`, which is a completely different animal.

Comment: @user694733: This question is about reversing the bits in a `uint16_t`, not about reversing the bits in a byte. The question I have now marked it as a duplicate of has answers covering 32 and 64 bits and a general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no C bitwise operator that does that, you have to implement it.

One way is to define a look-up table for some suitable amount of bits (8, or 4) and then chunk the value up and flip each chunk, then combine them together again.

Sounds like fun, let's code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t flip(uint16_t x)
{
  const uint16_t nibbles[] = { 0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15 };

  uint16_t out = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
  {
    const uint16_t here = nibbles[(x >> (4 * i)) & 15];
    out |= here << (4 * (3 - i));
  }
  return out;
}
```

Comment: 519 votes on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/746203/298225) suggest it is not all that uncommon. Bit-reversal is needed in some signal-processing algorithms, and some architectures provide an instruction for it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point, I removed the statement. Should have dupe-checked too, obvo. Thanks.